# Error while attaching an Elastic ip to an instance running in VPC

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, elastic-ip

I am facing an issue while attaching an Elastic IP to an instance running in VPC, I have checked all the configurations but can't resolve the issue. Could anyone please help me through this? Below is the screenshot of the error.

These are the steps that i did before getting the Error:-

-> Firstly taken an AMI of the running instance which was also configured in VPC

-> Then after with that AMI i have launched an instance in the same VPC and Subnet.

-> Here when the instance is up i have tried attaching and elasic ip(VPC Scope) but it throws an error saying "either public IP or allocation id must be specified" . I don't know what caused that??

[image: Elastic ip Error]

Comment: whats your trynig so far?

Comment: Missing a screenshot?

Comment: Hi @combo_ci,                                                                                     
                        Actually it was an instance launched using an AMI an i have tried using all the "Auto-assign Public IP" settings given at the Launch time.

Comment: Sorry Now added the Screen Shot

Comment: Welcome to SE @Teja. If you follow this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonVPC/latest/UserGuide/vpc-eips.html, which step is failing?

Comment: Thanks for the doc @Dusan Bajic . When i associate to the instance it says "either public ip or allocation id must be specified" .

Comment: can you make a screenshot the moment before you click and get the error?

Comment: hmm..sorry @Dusan Bajic . I don't have rights to post configurations.Any Alternative?

Comment: Please Edit your question and add details about exactly what steps you took that led to this error message. No need to tell us sensitive information (eg instance IDs), but please tell us what tried to do, otherwise we will not be able to offer you any advice.

Comment: Please expand on your 3rd bullet -- what values did you select when associating the Elastic IP address? (Feel free to hide sensitive data, but let us know what fields you used and where you got the values.)

Comment: @ John Rotenstein - Firstly i have created an E.Ip -> associate the E.ip -> Here it asks for Instance ID -> After selecting the Instance ID -> Click on "Done" -> Here it throws Error. Hope i met your requirement. Thank You!

Comment: Very strange! It's basically saying that a call to the `AssociateAddress()` command needs to be told which IP address to assign. For some reason, this information isn't being passed to the function. Could you try creating another Elastic IP address and associating it to the instance, to see if it works?

Comment: Hi @John Rotenstein - Even i have tried associating a New Elastic ip its throwing the same error and could you please brief me about what is "Associate Address"?

Comment: **Associate address** is the command you use when you link an Elastic IP address to an Amazon EC2 instance. Steps: EC2 console, Elastic IPs, Allocate New Address, Associate Address, select instance, click Associate, Done!

Comment: @John Rotenstein - But that is what i have done right??

Comment: I have no further suggestions. One possibility is that it is confused between EC2-VPC and EC2-Classic (the Elastic IP and Instance must be of the same type).

Comment: okey @John Rotenstein, will comment once the issue is resolved  - Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this problem as well and I resolved it by clicking the refresh button on the page where the elastic IPs are listed.